# Storing DATEPART in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there a way I can store a DATEPART parameter in a TABLE so I can pass it as a variable to DATEADD(...) later on. Something like this

```
CREATE TABLE abc
(
   Freq <some DATEPART type>,
   FromDate DATE,
   NumOfDays INT
)
```

and then in my view

```
CREATE VIEW abc
AS
SELECT DATEADD(Freq, NumOfDays, FromDate)
FROM abc
```

(yes, I know I can do this from DYNAMIC SQL but Views don't take dynamic sql and I would like to avoid using dynamic sql).

Comment: From the MSDN docs: *datepart - Is the part of date (a date or time value) for which an integer will be returned. **User-defined variable equivalents** are not valid.* -- this would indicate there's no way to store and pass the type of `DATEPART` you want to that function - dynamic SQL or a `CASE` statement are your only choices

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to use Dynamic SQL, no.

Since there is a limited number of DateParts you could potentially use a `CASE` statement like:

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN Freq = 'Year' THEN DATEADD(Year, NumOfDays, Fromdate)
           WHEN Freq = 'Day' THEN DATEADD(Day, NumOfDays, FromDate)
           ... END as 'MyField'
FROM Abc
```

Comment: That's exactly what I had... was trying to get around that also.

Comment: @Denis - if you don't want a case statement or dynamic SQL, then no you can't do what you want.  Is there a reason not to do a `CASE` statement?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look very good but may be like this

```
SELECT 
    Case Freq
        WHEN 'yyyy' THEN DATEADD(yyyy, NumOfDays, FromDate)
        WHEN 'yy' THEN DATEADD(yy, NumOfDays, FromDate)
        WHEN 'mm' THEN DATEADD(mm, NumOfDays, FromDate)
        ...
    END
```